# The adress without WWW points to the old server

Tags: web-hosting, url

I have just changed Web host but I have a small problem, the domain.com site points to my new server but www.domain.com is always on my former server.

How to remedy it?

Comment: Have you set up `domain.com` on the new server as well?

Answer (score 1):

Have you updated your name servers at your registrar to point to your new hosting account? If yes it is most likely your DNS cache.

Try viewing the website in Chrome Incognitor mode or private browsing in firefox and safari.

In windows open a command prompt and type `ifconfig /flushdns` and refresh your browser.

Comment: Yes, i was updated my name servers at my registrar. But i'm a shared hosting, i can't flush dns. The result in others browser is identical.

Comment: What is your domain name